# break while an iteration and after an iteration

Tags: python

In my 2 scripts it looks as the `break` statement can break out of the loop both: while the iteration process is running, and also after an iteration ends.
But I thought that `break` can merely break the loop while the iteration, and not after it.
I find it meaningful because the outputs vary depending on how the `break` functions with iterations.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(list)):
    if i ==1: 
        break 
    print("loop is broken")
```

output:

```
loop is broken
```

In the above example, according to the outcome, the `break` only breaks out of the loop after the first iteration ends.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in list:
    if i == 1:
        print("loop is broken")
        break
    print("string is not printed")
```

Output:

```
loop is broken
```

Now it contradicts the assumption that the `break` breaks only once the iterator finishes, otherwise `string is not printed` would have been printed.

Comment: The first value produced by `range(len(list))` is 0, not 1. `break` isn't reached until the *second* iteration.

Comment: `break` always behaves the same: it exits the loop *immediately*.

Comment: I see, now it makes more sense

Comment: You should never call a variable `list` because you overwrite the built-in with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you use `for i in range(len(list)):` meaning that `i` will only equal `1` on the second iteration, so 'loop is broken' gets printed.

In the second code snippet, you use `for i in list:`, so `i` equals `1` on the first iteration, so only 'loop is broken' has a chance to get printed before the break.